# EACCES error after updating firebase-admin

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I just updated firebase admin and when I try to acces my firebase functions code, after I run firebase serve, I get EACCES error. I mention that before the update, the code was working fine.

I tried reinstalling the node modules, reinstalling firebase and firebase admin, running the serve command as admin, and also adding 
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.15.0"
  },
to my package.json file

the full error:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "api"
!  Default "firebase-admin" instance created!
>  events.js:183
>        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>        ^
> 
>  Error: listen EACCES C:\Users\Berce\AppData\Local\Temp\firebase_emulator_invocation_2608.sock
>      at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1343:19)
>      at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
>      at Server.listen (net.js:1496:5)
>      at Function.listen (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
>      at Promise (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:359:46)
>      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
>      at C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:332:15
>      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
>      at C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:7:71
>      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
>      at __awaiter (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:3:12)
>      at ProcessHTTPS (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:329:12)
>      at C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:523:23
>      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
>      at fulfilled (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:4:58)
>      at <anonymous>
>      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
>      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:696:11)
>      at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
>      at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Comment: If you're having a problem with the Cloud Functions for Firebase emulator, post a bug report on its GitHub.  Bug reports don't belong on Stack Overflow.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Bear in mind also that "8.15.0" is not a valid value for "engines".  It should just be "8", or whatever major version of node you're targeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I found out that the problem was known by firebase team. Is reproduced on windows, and there is no known way to fix it. So for now I had to fall back.

Thank you!